# Sort collection by mdate field and get the latest 20 results (LIMIT) in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I've a collection called `messages` and I need to sort by `mdate` and get only the latest 20 results kind of LIMIT in SQL, how? I'm playing with this but without success:

```
db.getCollection('messages').find({}, {"sort" : ['mdate', 'asc']} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the last 20 documents you should [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort) your document in descending order and use the [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit) operator to return only 20 documents.

```
db.messages.find().sort({ 'mdate': -1 }).limit(20)
```